# Symfony custom user provider / salting password

Tags: php, authentication, symfony1, salt

I'm using DynamoDB for my application so the doctrine ORM isn't an option for me when it comes to authentication.

I've created a basic user provider and have it working perfectly when using a sha1 hash, however I'm completely stuck / don't understand how to get it working with salt.

FYI: My code is based on this [guide](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) from the manual

**Code:**

Once the 'new user' form has been submitted a grab the raw data and do the following then persist to the DB - this works fine:

```
    $salt = '79fdshjh408hjhgd87r5438ujl';
    $password = base64_encode(sha1($rawPassword.'{'.$salt.'}'));
```

When authenticating I have a 'userProvider' that requests the users details based on username from the DB - this also works fine and I'm returned all the details

```
//WebserviceUserProvider.php
$username = $userData['userName'];
$password = $userData['password'];
$roles[0] = 'ROLE_ADMIN';
$salt = '79fdshjh408hjhgd87r5438ujl';

return new WebserviceUser($username, $password, $salt, $roles);
```

the WebserviceUser file is a direct copy of the one in the [docs:](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)

security.yml

```
    security:
      encoders:
        HvH\SecurityBundle\Security\WebserviceUser: 
          algorithm:   sha1
          iterations: 1
          encode_as_base64: true
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The code itself looks correct when compared to the docs. What is the problem you are running in to?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the reply. Seems to have something to do with base64, I stopped using that and it started working. On a side note, is it possible to randomly generate the salt or am I best to make up any random string as I have in the example?

Comment: I would look up the FOSUserBundle. In that bundle I believe they randomly generate the salt and save it with the database with the rest of the user info.